# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find lGL when building Qt5 app in Qt Creator on Linux Mint

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, linker-errors, qt5

I'm porting my application from Qt4 to Qt5.  I installed Qt5.2.1 from the [online installer](https://qt-project.org/downloads) on Linux Mint 16 64-bit, in a vm on my MacBook Pro.  When I run qmake and build in Qt Creator, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

Do I need openGL?  I'm not using it when I build on Windows or OSX.  I'm very new to Linux, and far from expert in C++ or Qt.  I found a [post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29124) that included a hack to remove -lGL from mkspecs/common/linux.conf.  That worked.

My question is, assuming I don't need -lGL, what is the normal way to keep the linker from attempting to link it?  I imagine I do something in the .pro file, but what?

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 makes heavy use of OpenGL internally. On Windows OpenGL support is a bit flaky (you must install the original vendor drivers, because Microsoft strips OpenGL from the automatically installed drivers) and hence makes use of a built in OpenGL emulation layer library.

On Linux however OpenGL support is much better. You'll find at least the Mesa softpipe backend, if the GPU is not supported by the standard drivers. If the GPU *is* supported, then out-of-the-box OpenGL support in Linux has become pretty good over the past years.

On MacOS X OpenGL is actually the foundation of all the higher level graphics operations and hence part of the inner workings of the operating system; sounds great in theory, but is also a major obstacle for quick version turnaround, as every major OpenGL version bump mandates an operating system update.

Now, unless your installation of Linux is seriously outdated you actually should have a OpenGL library installed. If not (and your linker error tells you this), just install the Mesa development package.

Linux Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu which in turn is a Debian derivative. The command to install the Mesa development package for OpenGL is

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: I'm using the latest Linux Mint.  I have run the command you mention and it finished successfully.  I still get the same link error.  Perhaps to clarify my question:  is linking -lGL necessary on Linux for a simple "Hello World" program?  If not, it may not be necessary for my program either - in which case, how should I tell the linker not to include -lGL?

Comment: @DavidBurson: It's not necessary for a simple Hello World. And in fact any shared library you use (like Qt) that uses OpenGL should make the link internally without requiring your program to specify explicitly.

Comment: Thanks.  By experimenting with 2 Hello World programs, one as widget app and the other as a console app, it seems that the linker tries to link -lGL if the .pro file does not have QT -= gui.  So is it really true that if I need the gui module, I have to link -lGL on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint?  Or is -lGL something extra I may not need?

Comment: Maybe a light is dawning in my slow mind.  Maybe my build tries to link -lGL because I installed Qt on Mint from the online installer, rather than building from source as I did on Windows and OSX.  So maybe the Qt I installed was configured with OpenGL, and maybe that causes the gui module to depend on -lGL.  Does that sound correct?  If so, my choices are to build from source on Mint so I can eliminate OpenGL in my configure options, or find a way to make linking -lGL succeed, right?  Or am I way off?

Comment: @DavidBurson: With online installer do you mean the Mint package manager? If not, did you install something downloaded from the Qt project website? If the later is the case, please try to cleanse that from your system and install the packages through the distributions repository. Anyway it makes *no* sense for the build system to add OpenGL if QtGui ist *not* being used; it is QtGui that creates the dependency on OpenGL in the first place.

Comment: I did install Qt from what I downloaded from the Qt project website.  I want Qt 5.2.1, and I (being very new to all things Linux) have not figured out how to get it from the distributions repository.  Can you steer me the right direction to get Qt 5.2.1 from the distribution repository?

Comment: @DavidBurson: Mint is based on Debian. Debian testing (jessie) already has Qt5.2 packages in its repositories. So the first step is to add the Debian jessie repositories to your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList). Then `sudo apt-get update` and the libqt5 packages should show up when doing `apt-cache search libqt5`

Comment: I added this repository:  "deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main" and when I update, I get "W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553" - I have no idea what to do with that?

Comment: @DavidBurson: Oh, that means, that you'll have the PGP public keys of the Debian repository maintainers so that packages integrity can be verified. Details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139127/

Comment: still struggling with the public key issue, but I noticed that the Qt 5.2.1 packages are listed now in Package Manager.  Can I safely ignore the public key error?

Comment: @DavidBurson: Depends on your system configuration, but normally you can install packages anyway; you'll get a bunch of warnings which you ignore. This is a viable way to deal with this, until Milt caught up with their packages.