# Unable to access my off site MYSQL DB via a VSCode extension when it is running under WSL2

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm running Windows 11. I have my dev environment in Debian running via WSL2.

I have [this VSCode extension installed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-mysql-client2) (although I have tried multiple SQL VSCode extensions and they all act the same)

If I have a VSCode window open in a WSL2 instance I am unable to connect to my DB but if I have a normal VSCode window open I am able to use any extension to access my DB.

In both instances the DB connection details are identical.

I need to use a program called ScaleFT to create a secure tunnel to the DB, I'm assuming this is the cause of the issue in part.

I am able to connect to my local dev MYSQL DB running in docker from both a WSL and normal VSCode window.

Comment: I believe you are probably on the right track regarding the tunnel.  I assume that ScaleFT is running in Windows?  Is it a simple "tunnel" or more like a VPN where traffic is redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that WSL's network sharing with the host system seems to run into trouble a *lot* with VPN and Ad-Hoc tunnel sharing with the Windows host.

What worked best for me was just to install an independent client for the WSL host. I use Ubuntu personally but I bet this will be a drop-in for your Debian setup, too.

**Add the ScaleFT Repo to apt:**

```
echo "deb http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**Add the ScaleFT signing keys to your local keyring:**

```
curl -fsSL https://dist.scaleft.com/pki/scaleft_deb_key.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/scaleft-deb-key.gpg
```

**Pull package list and install the Linux tools:**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y scaleft-client-tools scaleft-url-handler
```

That should leave you with a ready copy of the sft client tool. You can test with:

```
sft --version
```

From there, you can [enroll your new WSL client](https://help.okta.com/asa/en-us/Content/Topics/Adv_Server_Access/docs/setup/enrolling-a-client.htm) and those connections *should* start working for you but, of course, your mileage may vary!

Comment: Thanks for that although I seem to be running into a problem when I try and run sudo apt update


Err:4 http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Comment: I managed to fix that issue by following the top comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139127/how-to-trust-a-apt-repository-debian-apt-get-update-error-public-key-is-not-av