# First pipeline fails during 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl' step - "Scalable FastAPI Applications on AWS" course

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, fastapi, docker-in-docker, testdriven.io

I’m on the “Tests and Code Quality” page of the course (Part 1, Chapter 5).   I have followed all of the steps to this point and have not had any issues.  In this section, I created the Dockerfile, and .gitlab-ci.yml files, and used copy/paste to be sure they are correct.  But, every time I try to run the pipeline I get a failure.  I have searched extensively to try to find a solution, but have not had any luck.  The log file shows the following for the error:

[Job build-python-ci-image log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp9nU.png)

I have poured over the Gitlab and Docker docs but have not been able to find a solution.  I have tried to use a different Python image (e.g., python:3.11-slim-bullseye) in the Docker file and also a different docker image in the .gitlab-ci.yml file (e.g., docker:24.0.6 and docker:24.0.6-dind) and while I get a different error, the pipeline still fails.

In the first case it seems to be failing to install cURL.  Changing the docker images causes that to succeed but then fails later during the ‘docker push’ script (the last line!).  Is it failing to upload to gitlab due to some issue with credentials?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139127/how-to-trust-a-apt-repository-debian-apt-get-update-error-public-key-is-not-av